# Top bar green reputation gain is missing 10 points

Tags: support, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Here's a screenshot having just clicked the achievements button with the two events that happened since I last clicked the button. Did 100 + 5 produce 95?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Probably a question where you had a +1 answer was removed. Loss of reputation due to such a thing is not shown in the top bar achievements dialog, but you should see it if ticking "Show removed posts" in your reputation tab. (Most likely on SO)

Comment: Shadow Wizard nailed it. Since this isn't an issue now and this isn't helpful for anyone in the future what's the etiquette around here? Should I delete this question now?

Comment: Well this can explain the same "bug" in other cases so might be better to leave it, I will post my comment as answer later when having some time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nice. Maybe a title change now? What do you think would be easy to find?

Comment: Well, I've put my idea, feel free to change it if you got something better. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's tricky guessing what would help folks find this, that's why I punted to you. X-P I think as long as we have "reputation" "missing" and "points" in there that's the best we can do.

Comment: True. I believe this has already been asked, one way or the other, with very similar answer, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually such a thing means that a question you answered got deleted, and you had upvotes on your answer, hence losing reputation. Such events are not displayed in the top bar achievements dialog,  however they are visible in the reputation tab of your profile, if you tick the "Show removed posts":

> [image]

In the above example screenshot, [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405192/the-code-below-is-in-window-i-want-the-web-code-for-this/5405262#5405262) was removed by automatic process, however there can be many reasons why question with upvoted answers can be removed, e.g. being off topic.